# Yahoo exchange rate API does not give the right exchange rate

Tags: php, csv, yahoo-finance

So, I downloaded (and to be parsed in PHP) an IDR to USD exchange rate like this:

`http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=IDRUSD=X&f=nl1d1t1`

This give me resulting file like this:

`"IDR to USD",0.0001,"1/26/2015","5:07am"`

But when checking with Google, Indonesian Rupiah to USD rate is 0.000080. Is this Yahoo's fault or I am making a wrong API call? Or is there any other solution for this in PHP? (If possible I don't want to use the OpenExchange API, I will have to remove and tweak an entire code).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that yahoo finance lacks some accuracy for your use.
I get the same result using their webpage.
But if I enter 10 IDR to USD i get 0.0008.

If I invert it I get a better result:
1 USD = 12499.9502 IDR.

You could do the inverted request, and just invert it back in your application.

[Example from Yahoo Finance webpage](http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-converter/#from=USD;to=IDR;amt=1)